# Can a static inner class extend its outer class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
public class Outer {

    public static class Inner extends Outer {

    }
}
```

It seems to compile with my openjdk8 compiler but IntelliJ 2019.1 complains :
*Cannot access Outer*

I think this might be an IntelliJ bug..

EDIT: I confirm this was an IntelliJ bug. I solved this by installing the IntelliJ with the bundled OpenJDK 11.

Comment: It should compile. See for example [Point2D.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/geom/Point2D.java) in the JDK.

Comment: Yes that's fine, and it works fine in IntelliJ 2019.1.2  when I try it. Is this really all there is to your code or is there more?

Comment: Works under IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2 too

Comment: A good reading about this is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3

Answer (score 3):

This works using OpenJDK 11:

```java
public class Outer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.foo();
    }

    void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo from Outer");
    }

    public static class Inner extends Outer {
        @Override
        void foo() {
            System.out.println("foo from Inner");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
foo from Inner
```

Comment: I can compile it but IntelliJ still complains so I think it's an IntelliJ bug.

Comment: JDK8 or JDK11 did not make a difference.

Comment: When I upstepped my IntelliJ to use the bundled JDK11 instead of the bundled JDK8, it worked. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It should work and it works on my machine.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2
Build #IU-191.7141.44

jdk1.8.0_201
```

A public nested class can be extended as any other top-level class visible to the subclass-to-be. It is definitely not a Java issue regarding inheritance, or visibility.

It might be an IntelliJ issue concerning the way it scans the package/project. Make sure there is no other `Outer` classes involved. Yes, it's likely IDEA found another `Outher` and sneakily tried to access it. Check out your imports as well.

Answer (score -2):

yes, you can. here is the sample.

```
public class SampleClass {
       static abstract class Test{
          int num = 300;
          public abstract void display();
       }
       class DemoClass extends Test{
          public void display() {
             System.out.println("Hi how are you");
          }
       }
       public static void main(String args[]){
          SampleClass obj = new SampleClass();
          obj.new DemoClass().display();
       }
    }
```

o/p: Hi how are you